# How to work out the probability of finding an item in a box when each box has a different chance of finding the item?

Tags: probability

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402569/probability-of-finding-item-in-a-box), but that only seems to work when all boxes have the same probability of finding the item. What I want to know is, if I have *n* amount of boxes, and the probability of finding an item in each box is *$k_1$*, *$k_2$*, *$k_3$*... *$k_n$*, what would the formula be for finding the item in at least 1 box?

For example, if I had 3 boxes, and Box1 had a 25% chance of finding the item, Box2 had a 40% chance of finding the item and Box3 had a 35% chance of finding the item, what is the probability that I find the item in at least 1 of the boxes (not restricted to exactly 1). My first thought was to add them together, since you want to find the item in one box OR another, but of course if you add them all together you get 100%, and you're not guaranteed to get the item.

Comment: The probability of finding an item in at least one box can be found by subtracting the probability that the item is found in none of the boxes from $1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig But what is the probability that the item is found in none of the boxes? Would it be (1 - 0.25) * (1 - 0.4) * (1 - 0.35)? Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. The formula would be: 

`(1 - ((1 - (k1 / 100)) * (1 - (k2 / 100)) * (1 - (k3 / 100)) * ... * (1 - (kn / 100)))) * 100`

Where all probabilities are in percentages.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.